# Upgrading storium level after backing

Tags: storium

When 'backing' [Storium](http://storium.com) now for $10, can you later 'upgrade' your level still to for example the $40 level, or would you then have to pay the full $40?

The reason I am asking is that if it doesn't cost me any extra I would like to try out Storium for the $10, however as I think I am going to like it, if upgrading your level is not possible I might just go for a more expensive level straight from the get go. Put differently, if you have a Storium account, do you see an option to upgrade your level anywhere in the interface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I asked @Storium on Twitter:

> @Storium quick q: if I pay $10 for Beta Player access, do I later have
>   to pay the full $40 for The Deal access, or do I get a discount?

, and this was [the answer](https://twitter.com/Storium/status/489168542177435649):

> @adrianovaroli You can upgrade at any time (up until our public
>   launch) and only have to pay the difference!

I also asked for a link to that policy, and the answer was:

> ...if you back us at $10 and then go to your profile page, you'll see
>   the price-adjusted update options listed.

Comment: Haha, now that I made an account it indeed is quite 'in your face'. Turns out looking up an screenshot of the interface would've been enough, but thanks a lot for the help :D .